# Scroll down page event for x seconds

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am currently able to scroll down a page with the help of CasperJS. I saw this [article](http://www.andykelk.net/tech/web-scraping-with-casperjs) on how to scroll infinite pages based on the visibility of certain attributes. However I don't want to base it on the visibility of an element but was wondering if there is a way to set a timer on how long it should stay scrolling down before exiting out. How would be able to such thing?

```
//function to scroll
function tryAndScroll(casper) {
    casper.page.scrollPosition = {
        top: casper.page.scrollPosition["top"] + 40000,
        left: 0
    };
}

/**
 * Everything starts here!
 * I use the mobile version of facebook as the DOM is waaay simpler to scrape.
 */
casper.start('https://www.somesite.com', function() {
});

casper.then(function() {
    tryAndScroll(this);
});

casper.then(function() {;
    this.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
function tryAndScroll(casper) {
    casper.page.scrollPosition = {
        top: casper.page.scrollPosition["top"] + 300,
        left: 0
    };
}

casper.start(url).then(function() {
    var self = this;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        tryAndScroll(self);
    }, 100); // retry interval
    self.wait(10000 /* infinite scroll timeout */, function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
}).run();
```

Since `setInterval()` is not a CasperJS step function, this essentially break out of the control flow of CasperJS. The `wait()` is necessary so that CasperJS doesn't execute something else during the scroll.

Also, you can't use a scroll distance of 40000 pixels. This is too big and PhantomJS won't be able to take a screenshot.

Comment: If I understood correctly, then essentially CasperJs scrolls for 10 seconds, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Doing roughly 100 scroll iterations.

Comment: Hmm somehow the scroll down must be happening on an empty http response. For some reason I am not able to snapshot the last place where the scrolled happened. [Code Gist](https://gist.github.com/MaryCoding/2fa5844c72ed6f03d1de)

Comment: The wikipedia page in your gist doesn't change depending on scroll. It looks (almost) the same before and after the scroll. Also, the white part of the screenshot has nothing to do with scrolling. It's a bug of Wikipedia (or PhantomJS or both).

Comment: I manage to manipulate the view port through casperjs which then allowed for image screen capture